# Generate a text file with the name of current time in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python v2.x on Windows 8 bit-64.

The question is, I failed to generate a `txt` file named as real time.

Please see the code I have now:

```
import sys
import datetime

def write():

    # try:
        currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        print currentTime #output: 2016-02-16 16:25:02.992000
        file = open(("c:\\", currentTime, ".txt"),'a')   # Problem happens here
        print >>file, "test"
        file.close()
```

I tried different ways to modify the line file = open(("c:\....)) but failed to create a text file like 2016-02-16 16:25:02.992000.txt

Any advice please?

Comment: Perhaps it's folder permissions issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows, `:` is an illegal character in a file name. You can never create a file that has a name like `16:25:02`.

Also, you are passing a tuple instead of a string to `open`.

Try this:

```
    currentTime = currentTime.replace(':', '_')
    file = open("c:\\" + currentTime + ".txt",'a')
```

Comment: Thx Rob, It works! :) One more question, I tried to replace : to \, but failed with IOError " No such file or directory". Does it mean ":" cannot be replaced by "/" ?

Comment: Hi @Amber.G. You can click the check mark to the left of Rob's response to confirm that Rob's response answers your question.

Comment: @Amber.G \ is the escape character in python so you would need to use "\\"; and anyway both \ and / indicate a directory for Windows so cannot be used as part of the file name. Pick some other character or just remove the : altogether. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

Comment: Thank you very much, @Rob. Your answer is accepted and up. :)

Answer (score -2):

Here's a more efficient way to write your code.

```
import sys
import datetime

def write():
        currentTime = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        currentTime = currentTime.replace(':', '_')
        with open("c:\\{0}.txt".format(currentTime), 'a') as f:
             f.write("test")
```

Comment: You passed a tuple to the **open** function which is not allowed. Concatenating strings in python is done by **string1 + string2**.

Comment: fixed it I was looking at OP post to stencil.